# Detect deviation from selected route in android map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to draw route between two points. I did this successfully. But how to know if the user deviated from drawn path or not. So that I can suggest user to notify alternative path to reach their destination. Like what google map navigation did. Am working on it and till now I could't find any answer for this. Please suggest some approach to me to find deviation from selected route.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(...) from [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/).

Comment: I have the same requirement. Is there an iOS library also?

Comment: I believe it's open source, you can port it to iOS.